Numlock LED turns off, GDM login screen
My NumLock LED (and LED only, not the key functionality) is off on the GDM password input screen. Sometimes, the LED is already off when waking with NumLock on. If the LED is on when waking, it turns off when a key is pressed.
I have tried both gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard remember-numlock-state on and gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state on as myself and as user Debian-gdm.
The NumLock LED behaviour seems to be inconsistent across sleep/wake cycles. Sometimes the LED's on, sometimes it's off, but NumLock proper (the number function) seems to be on across the board.
I have to press NumLock twice to return it to its ON state with the LED on as well.
Do you have any idea as to why that is, and how I could fix the issue?

With waking do you mean to turn it on/enabling?

I mean when the computer is sleeping and I turn it on again (not booting).
